# VideoCloudSamplePlayer iOS sample app video renditions

Tags: xcode, video, brightcove

I'm testing the [Brightcove's Swift VideoCloudSamplePlayer iOS sample app](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/ios-player-samples/tree/master/Player/VideoCloudBasicPlayer)  with one of the my videos of my account.

I basically want to know if there is an easy way get/see the video renditions of the video I'm playing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of sources from the `BCOVVideo` object as follows:

```
-(void)playbackController:(id<BCOVPlaybackController>)controller didAdvanceToPlaybackSession:(id<BCOVPlaybackSession>)session
{
    BCOVVideo *video = session.video;

    for (BCOVSource *source in video.sources)
    {

    }
}
```

An example of this can be found in the Offline Player sample from the same [iOS Sample repo](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/ios-player-samples/tree/master/Offline/OfflinePlayer/swift)